# Combine two SQL statements, set a status

Tags: sql

I currently have two SQL statements that I'd like to combine into one, and set a status if it meets each one. I've posted some massively stripped down code below:

```
select * from database where date1 < SYSDATE
select * from database where date2 < SYSDATE
```

Ideally, I'd like it so if it meets the criteria in the first statement, it'd set a flag of 'status1' and if it doesn't meet that criteria, but meets the second statement's criteria I'd like to set a flag of 'status2' - hope that makes sense!

For example the data would be like: Name | ID | Status

Thanks :)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Where is Status1 or Status2? Are they columns in a table or values in a table? Is this `database` table related in anyway to the table you are updating? Your expected outcome isn't really 100% clear.

Comment: `sysdate` indicates it's Oracle (or DB2 with the Oracle compatibility turned on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
select Name, ID, CASE 
     WHEN date1 < SYSDATE THEN 1 
     WHEN date2 < SYSDATE THEN 2
END as Status
from mytable
where date1 < SYSDATE or date2 < SYSDATE
```

Comment: Lots of awesome replies, but this is the one for me I think, works perfectly (although I appreciate the other solutions do too) and returns just what I needed. Love this site, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from ( 
  select name, id, 'status1' as status
  from some_table 
  where date1 < SYSDATE

  UNION ALL

  select name, id, 'status2'
  from some_table 
  where date2 < SYSDATE
)
```

Comment: Didn't think of using the UNION statement, d'oh! This is a great solution, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     flag =
        CASE
        WHEN  date1 < SYSDATE THEN
                'status1'
        ELSE
                'status2'
        END
WHERE   date1 < SYSDATE
        OR
        date2 < SYSDATE
```

Comment: Like I said to Ben, this is a brilliant solution - thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you wanted to *UPDATE* the status...

```
UPDATE database 
SET flag = CASE WHEN date1 < SYSDATE THEN 'status1' WHEN date2 < SYSDATE THEN 'status2' ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you - I was actually writing a new view, but updating a flag in the main database could actually be an even better solution!